# Qt/QML: WebEngineView and ScrollView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtwebengine

I have desktop app in which I have a `ScrollView` that contains a `ListView`, in which the delegates each contain multiple widgets, including a `WebEngineView`:

```
ScrollView
{
    id: myScrollView
    anchors.fill: parent;

    ListView
    {
        id: myListView
        delegate: Item
        {
            Rectangle
            {
                Text ...
                Text ...
                // other stuff

                WebEngineView
                {
                    id: myWebEngineView
                    Component.onCompleted:
                    {
                        loadHtml(model.modelData.someHTMLData);
                    }                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with scrolling. On Mac, if I use the touchpad to scroll, the `ListView` only scrolls if the mouse is hovered over one of the non-`WebEngineView` widgets.

I suspect the `WebEngineView` widgets are trapping the mouse messages but I cannot find a way stop this from happening. How can I do this?

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back and eventually gave up on trying to have multiple `WebEngineViews` in a list, rewriting the `ListView` entirely in HTML/Javascript.

Comment: @MrEricSir I have thought several times about going down this same path, even though I'm trying really hard to avoid it. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I know about Qt Quick is that it has [input focus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html).

According to this, you can play with `FocusScope`s and [focus property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#focus-prop).

For example set `ListView`'s focus to true, lay delegate into `FocusScope` with `focus: false`. Or set `WebEngineView`'s focus to false.

Hope this helps =)